# How to expand this nested list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, nested-loops

Consider the below function:

It takes a list of lists as an input and finds all combinations of elements from each of those lists.

```
def product(llist):
    result = [[]]

    for lst in llist:
        result = [x + [y] for x in result for y in lst]

    return result
```

For eg:

```
product([[1,2], [3], [4,5]])
```

would return:

```
[[1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5]]
```

I'm trying to understand how this function works and hence trying to expand the list comprehension.

Here's a try:

```
def product2(llist):
    result = [[]]
    for lst in llist:
        for x in result:
            result = []
            for y in lst:
                result.append(x+[y])

    return result
```

this doesn't give me the correct result, it returns:

```
[[2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5]]
```

and I understand this incorrect result as per the definition of `product2`. But I'm not able to expand the original `product` function to understand how it is working.

Can someone elaborate the nested list comprehension in `product` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list comprehension is creating a new list for each element in `lst`, and creates further new lists by combining this small single element list with all the lists that are already in `result`.

So, for example if `result = [ [1, 2], [3, 4] ]` and `lst = [10, 11]`, new result would be `[[1, 2, 10], [1, 2, 11], [3, 4, 10], [3, 4, 11]]`.

And it's doing this for each `lst` in `llist`:

```
def product2(llist):
    result = [[]]
    for lst in llist:
        new_result = [] # let's manually build out new result
        for existing in result:            
            for element in lst:
                new_result.append(existing + [element])
        result = new_result # update result for next lst
    return result
```

Comment: very nice I was missing that last peice

Comment: @vash_the_stampede thanks. It's easy to overlook that it's actually 3 loops.

Answer (score 1):

It helps if you print the partial values of `result`, like this:

```
def product(llist):
    result = [[]]

    for lst in llist:
        result = [x + [y] for x in result for y in lst]
        print(result)

    return result
```

First of all, the innner `list` of results is empty, so it will create a new inner list for each element in the first inner list passed:

```
[[1], [2]]
```

Then in the second pass, each inner list in the result will be replaced by itself plus each element in the second inner list passed as parameter:

```
[[1, 3], [2, 3]]
```

And then, when you have a inner parameter list with more than one element, it will replicate the current existing inner lists in the result

```
[[1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5]]
```

It happens like this because in one pass through the list comprehension the list in question will not be updated. It will be updated only at the end of the comprehension.

Another way you could see this is like a grid:

```
------------------
|    |  1  |  2  |
------------------
| [] | [1] | [2] |
------------------

result = [[1],[2]]

---------------
|     |   3   |
---------------
| [1] | [1,3] |
---------------
| [2] | [2,3] |
---------------

result = [[1,3],[2,3]]

-----------------------------
|       |    4    |    5    |
-----------------------------
| [1,3] | [1,3,4] | [1,3,5] |
-----------------------------
| [2,3] | [2,3,4] | [2,3,5] |
-----------------------------

result = [[1,3,4],[2,3,4],[1,3,5],[2,3,5]]
```

With this in mind, the version without comprehension will need a temporary variable to hold the updated values:

```
def product2(llist):
    result = [[]]
    for lst in llist:
        temp_res = []
        for x in result:
            for y in lst:
                temp_res.append(x+[y])
        result = temp_res

    return result
```